# Register/Login/Sign in pages with or without main menu?

Tags: navigation, menu, login

I see a recurring pattern in Register/Login/Sign in/Recover Pass/Etc pages of bigger sites, where they avoid using the full length of the main menu top bar. Frequently, they just leave the essentials like a link back to the home page and maybe a currency/language selector.

Is there any good reason for this?

Is it a good or bad practice to hide the main menu (or custom build a smaller menu for the login area)?

Comment: Could you illustrate your question with some mockups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

One possible reason for hiding the menu might be trying to keep the user focused on the task at hand. The more links you present, the more distractions and the more likely a person will choose one and leave the page. If your main goal is to get a person to register, you generally don't want this person to leave the registration page.

That said, there could be possible downsides. A user might get more disoriented without the standard menu up top. This is something to consider when designing and something to test out.

Comment: It's a good explanation, thanks. I managed to come up with a similar conclusion; the objective will dictate what should be shown to the user. Contextualizing, i need my job candidates to fill in, at register, the minimum profile information without distractions and submit it, in order to capture essential data with consent for the marketing dept. Which tends to be the universal objective, since user data is so valuable nowadays...